# c# object ignore months properties maintain neighbor relation while performing calculation

Tags: c#, dictionary, nearest-neighbor

I have a class that contains months property:

```
public class Item
{
   public Item()
   {

   }

   public decimal Jan { get; set; }
   public decimal Feb { get; set; }
   public decimal Mar { get; set; }
   public decimal Apr { get; set; }
   public decimal May { get; set; }
   public decimal Jun { get; set; }
   public decimal Jul { get; set; }
   public decimal Aug { get; set; }
   public decimal Sep { get; set; }
   public decimal Oct { get; set; }
   public decimal Nov { get; set; }
   public decimal Dec { get; set; }
}
```

There is also a `Dictionary<string, decimal>`

```
Dictionary<string, decimal> values = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
values.add("Jan", 10.00);
values.add("Feb", 10.00);
values.add("Mar", 10.00);
values.add("Apr", 10.00);
values.add("May", 10.00);
values.add("Jun", 10.00);
values.add("Jul", 10.00);
values.add("Aug", 10.00);
values.add("Sep", 10.00);
values.add("Oct", 10.00);
values.add("Nov", 10.00);
values.add("Dec", 10.00);
```

the decimal values in the values dictionary can be any decimal values, for demo purpose I added 10.00.

I need to calculate these values in the following way:

```
Item.Jan = values["Jan"];
Item.Feb = Item.Jan + values["Feb"];
Item.Mar = Item.Feb + values["Mar"];
Item.Apr = Item.Mar + values["Apr"];
Item.May = Item.Apr + values["May"];
Item.Jun = Item.May + values["Jun"];
Item.Jul = Item.Jun + values["Jul"];
Item.Aug = Item.Jul + values["Aug"];
Item.Sep = Item.Aug + values["Sep"];
Item.Oct = Item.Sep + values["Oct"];
Item.Nov = Item.Oct + values["Nov"];
Item.Dec = Item.Nov + values["Dec"];
```

So far so good. Everything works nice.

The problem is: I need to ignore certain months property from `Item` class. The ignored months will have value 0.

If the dictionary contains the following values:

```
Dictionary<string, decimal> values = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
values.add("Feb", 10.00);
values.add("Mar", 10.00);
values.add("Apr", 10.00);
values.add("Jun", 10.00);
values.add("Jul", 10.00);
values.add("Aug", 10.00);
values.add("Oct", 10.00);
values.add("Nov", 10.00);
values.add("Dec", 10.00);
```

notice `Jan, May, Sep` are missing, how can I perform my calculation, with the values provided within the dictionary and also maintain the relation in the calculation from the previous month? The first month in the dictionary is considered the first one. The `Item` first month is always equal with the value from the dictionary only.

the calculation in this case will be:

```
Item.Jan = 0.00;
Item.Feb = values["Feb"];   // Jan is missing from dictionary first month is Feb
Item.Mar = Item.Feb + values["Mar"];
Item.Apr = Item.Mar + values["Apr"];
Item.May = 0.00;
Item.Jun = Item.Apr + values["Jun"]; // May is missing, Jun = previous available month (Apr) + dictionary value of Jun
Item.Jul = Item.Jun + values["Jul"];
Item.Aug = Item.Jul + values["Aug"];
Item.Sep = 0.00;
Item.Oct = Item.Aug + values["Oct"]; // Sep is missing, Oct = previous available month (Aug) + dictionary value of Aug
Item.Nov = Item.Oct + values["Nov"];
Item.Dec = Item.Nov + values["Dec"];
```

EDIT:

To make it more clear:

When all months data is provided in the Dictionary, my calculation works fine.

- item.Jan = value["Jan"];
- item.Feb = item.Jan + value["Feb"];
- and so forth

When certain months are missing from the Dictionary, the calculation should be like this:

- missing months have value 0
- the first key from dictionary will define the first property in the Item class that will have it's value = to the dictionary["key"] value.

My only problem is maintaining the relation with the previous item, in case May is missing, item.Jun = item.Apr + value["Jun"] and so forth.

Comment: Seems like an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Try this : Item.Jan =  values.ContainsKey("Jan") ? values["Jan"] : 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use TryGetValue to extract a value from the Dictionary without knowing if the Key exists or not

```
decimal temp;
decimal runningTotal = 0m;

// Jan doesn't exist, so temp will default to zero
values.TryGetValue("Jan", out temp);
runningTotal += temp;
item.Jan = (temp == 0m ? temp : runningTotal);

values.TryGetValue("Feb", out temp);
runningTotal += temp;
item.Feb = (temp == 0m ? temp : runningTotal);

values.TryGetValue("Mar", out temp);
runningTotal += temp;
item.Mar = (temp == 0m ? temp : runningTotal);

values.TryGetValue("Apr", out temp);
runningTotal += temp;
item.Apr = (temp == 0m ? temp : runningTotal);

// May doesn't exist, so temp will default to zero
// and Item.May get a zero for its value 
// runningTotal is still set to the value of Apr
values.TryGetValue("May", out temp);
runningTotal += temp;
item.May = (temp == 0m ? temp : runningTotal);

// Resume the sums with the value of Jun
values.TryGetValue("Jun", out temp);
runningTotal += temp;
item.Jun = (temp == 0m ? temp : runningTotal);

... and so on for the other months
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Now you are marked in my book at the "My Heroes" page!

Answer (score 0):

With a alike answer, using TryGetValue too, a have made this 2 methods:

```
    public decimal GetValuesFromDictionary(Dictionary<string, decimal> values)
    {
        Jan = GetValueFromKey(values, "Jan");
        Feb = Jan + GetValueFromKey(values, "Feb");  
        Mar = Feb + GetValueFromKey(values, "Mar");
        Apr = Mar + GetValueFromKey(values, "Apr");
        May = Apr + GetValueFromKey(values, "May");
        Jun = Apr + GetValueFromKey(values, "Jun"); 
        Jul = Jun + GetValueFromKey(values, "Jul");
        Aug = Jul + GetValueFromKey(values, "Aug");
        Sep = Aug + GetValueFromKey(values, "Sep");
        Oct = Sep + GetValueFromKey(values, "Oct"); 
        Nov = Oct + GetValueFromKey(values, "Nov");
        Dec = Nov + GetValueFromKey(values, "Dec");

        return Dec;
    }

    private decimal GetValueFromKey(Dictionary<string,decimal> values, string key)
    {
        decimal temp;

        values.TryGetValue(key, out temp);

        return temp;
    }
```

Testing your case with values, is correctly ?

```
Dictionary<string, decimal> values = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
            values.Add("Feb", 10);
            values.Add("Mar", 10);
            values.Add("Apr", 10);
            values.Add("Jun", 10);
            values.Add("Jul", 10);
            values.Add("Aug", 10);
            values.Add("Sep", 10);
            values.Add("Oct", 10);
            values.Add("Nov", 10);
            values.Add("Dec", 10);

            Decimal total = 0;
            Item Item = new Item();

        total = Item.GetValuesFromDictionary(values);
```

Returned me the right value =D

Answer (score 0):

Keep a decimal type value called `PreviousValid` and initially set it to `Items["Jan"];`. Now change your code from

```
item.Jun = item.Apr + value["Jun"];
```

to like

```
PreviousValid = (item.Apr != null) ? item.Apr : PreviousValid;
item.Jun = PreviousValid + value["Jun"];
```

Make this modification to all "item.*xxx*" assignments and your code should work fine.